# How fast is Andromeda approaching in miles per hour

Tags: galaxy, amateur-observing

Apparently Andromeda is going to get here in 5 billion years and is 2.5 million light years away. I tried to work this out myself but I'm not sure I believe the answer..

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: As I am sure my work is probably wrong I would rather not...

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26745/123208 & https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/753/1/8

Comment: Cheers. I am glad I didn't show my working. I was out by a factor of ten.

Comment: Please show your work even if it wrong. Showing your work acknowledges that you have shown effort. The fact that you were wrong is the reason you asked this question: https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/429/35206

Comment: It's not bad to show something where there is a flaw in the math. It's worse to not - and not learn from ones own mistakes, and repeat them. The aim of this site is that everyone can learn from questions. Also especially in astronomy and astrophyics: a factor of 10 is sometimes easy to explain when starting with different assumptions about the initial conditions, making neither calculation wrong.

Answer (score 2):

## About 670,000 miles per hour

Thanks to blueshifting, we have been able to pin the velocity of the Andromeda Galaxy at about [300 kilometers per **SECOND**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda%E2%80%93Milky_Way_collision#Certainty:%7E:text=Way%20at%20about-,300%20km/s), which when converted, yields a approximate value of about 670,000 mph.